# sql query to select top result from each player?

Tags: php, sql

(sql query in PHP)

```
$sqlAS = "SELECT * FROM  results, players WHERE results.codeplayer=players.codeplayer GROUP BY results.codeplayer ORDER BY points Desc, time Asc ";
```

I want the query to produce a list with only the best result for each player (the db has several results for each player).

It works fine except that I get the best result in points for each player but not ordered then by the best time too as reflected in the SORT BY part of the SQL

For example if John has the following results

```
400 points 5:00 time   // in minutes
400 points 4:00 time
500 points 5:00 time
500 points 4:00 time
300 points 2:00 time
```

I get

```
John - 500 points - 5:00
```

but I need

```
 John - 500 - 4:00
```

which is the best result for John in points with less time.

I guessed that  `"ORDER BY points Desc, time Asc"` would take charge of that.

It seems that the `GROUP BY` puts the best result in points first regardless of time

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this (assuming that you have the columns with such names, because you haven't provided your table structure):

```
    $sqlAS = "SELECT p.*, r.codeplayer, r.points, min(r.`time`) 
FROM  results r JOIN players p ON r.codeplayer=p.codeplayer 
JOIN (select codeplayer, max(points) as points from results) res_max 
on (res_max.codeplayer = r.codeplayer AND res_max.points = r.points) 
GROUP BY r.codeplayer";
```

Comment: Wow I googled and found similar query strings with join and these are well above my level, really confusing. I don't know where res_max comes from, for example, and why min(r.`time`) with quotes or why "results r"? causes en error. Wish there was an easier way. Thanks

Comment: res_max is the name for a derived table: `(select codeplayer, max(points) as points from results) res_max` . I put the backticks around time so that it would not clash with mysql TIME method. You might try to remove them (i am not even sure if you have column called time, and in any case you need to provide the structure of your tables (field names and types) to get a better answer).